# SQL UPDATE Automation

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a query in the form of an UPDATE statement. Lets say it's open rate for an email campaign, in this example the city is London.

I want to run this query for 80 cities every month and have the results represented in 2018_Cities table. Is there a way I can automate this so I don't have to type all the cities every month?

Don't feel obliged to supply code you can just point me in the direction of the process if you want and I can investigate but I'm struggling to find the words to ask Google!

```
UPDATE 2018_Cities SET openRate = (
SELECT ROUND((
SELECT (
SELECT COALESCE( SUM(opens),0) 
FROM 0118
WHERE siteshort 
IN('London')) + (
SELECT COALESCE( SUM(opens),0) 
FROM 0218
WHERE siteshort 
IN('London')) 
as result) / 
(SELECT (
SELECT COALESCE( SUM(recipients),0) 
FROM 0118
WHERE siteshort 
IN('London')) + (
SELECT COALESCE( SUM(recipients),0) 
FROM 0218
WHERE siteshort 
IN('London')) 
as result) * 100, 1)) WHERE siteshort = ('London');
```

Comment: "Run this query" doesn't really help anyone else understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
UPDATE 2018_Cities c JOIN
       (SELECT siteshort, SUM(opens) / NULLIF(SUM(RECIPIENTS), 0) as new_openrate
        FROM `0118` t
        GROUP BY siteshort
       ) t
       ON c.siteshort = t.siteshort
    SET c.openRate = new_openrate;
```

Your logic is rather hard to follow, but the idea is the same.  Write a subquery to produce the calculations.  Then use `JOIN` to bring in the new values.

Note that `0118` is a ridiculous table name.  You should fix the names in your data model.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is the thread I need I think and will look into using JOIN in this instance.